# how to get min/max of user input?

Tags: java

when the max is printed the result is always -1, -1 should never be used in the calculations. -1 should only stop the code.
min is always 2147483647, this is obviously not correct.

```
public static void main(string [] args){
findMinMax(){    
{do{System.out.print("Type a number (or -1 to stop): ");
    num = console.nextInt();
    }while(num != -1);{
    }if (min < num) {
    min = num;
    }if (num > max) {
    max = num;
    } 
    System.out.println("maximum was : " + max);
    System.out.println("minimum was : " + min);
    }
}
}
```

example
if the numbers 5, 2, 17, -1, are inputted in that order, the result should be

```
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 5
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 2
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 17
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 8
Type a number (or -1 to stop): -1
Maximum was 17
Minimum was 2
```

the result is currently

```
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 5
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 2
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 17
Type a number (or -1 to stop): 8
Type a number (or -1 to stop): -1
maximum was : -1
minimum was : 2147483647
```

i have hit a mental roadblock and cant figure it out.

Comment: Please correctly format your code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `min = num` and **not** `num = min`? Also *you have to use both the `if` conditions inside the loop.*

Comment: the code above simply won't compile, please post working code

Comment: Your code should be a [mre], which means it must include all the import statements, the class definition, and the main() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code block has some issues.

1. your conditional check for min, max was not correct.
2. plus you must put min, max checking block inside the loop

Check the below code and correct yours:

```
int num = 0;
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

do {
    System.out.println("Type a number (or -1 to stop): ");
    
    num = console.nextInt();
    if(num == -1)  
        break;
    
    if (num < min){
        min = num;
    }
    
    if(num > max){
        max = num;
    }
} while (true);

System.out.println("maximum was : " + max);
System.out.println("minimum was : " + min);
```